# (Array|Linked)BlockingQueue has good `offer` performance, but why is `take` way too slow?

Tags: java, clojure

I have a Clojure network application, basic structure is like this:

- Server has one LinkedBlockingQueue or ArrayBlockingQueue (I have tried both)
- Multiple threads accept network connections, and `offer` work to the queue
- One thread `take` from the queue in an infinite loop and work on each item taken

And I have noticed severe performance issue with `take` call:

- Threads are `offer`ing to the queue at a very fast rate, and the queue takes them all very quickly
- The one worker thread `take` from the queue at a very very slow rate (more than 200 times slower than the speed of `offer`)
- CPU usage is very very low - so the worker is not busy at all

Without using the queue, in a benchmark situation, the same workload is able to be maximize CPU usage and be done at a satisfactory speed.

So what is the best queuing technique to use in this scenario?

Here's my code (less than 100 lines);

https://github.com/HouzuoGuo/Aurinko/blob/master/src/Aurinko/core.clj

Edit, details of my observation:

- I benchmarked request processing speed, it works at approximately 8,000 requests per second without using a queue.
- I made the server program to print a debug message when it queues a request, and another message when it finishes processing a request.
- I made a simple client program to send approximately 1,000 requests per second to the server.
- The server queues all the requests in time, and the queue becomes many thousands of elements long.
- Worker (request processor) appears to be working at only about 150 requests per second, according to the debug messages.

Edit:

Thanks for everyone's help. I have confirmed that blocking queue is not the thing causing the performance issue. Although I have not found the performance bottleneck in my application, but there has to be one somewhere.

Final edit:

Thank you everyone. The performance bottleneck was caused by network IO rather than the blocking queue.

Comment: I am not sure how you are measuring delay as I can't read clojure but take() will wait as required.  This can appear to make take() slow when really the queue is empty.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I understand that `.take` blocks until an element is available. In my scenario, many thousands of requests are queued (those blocking queues are working well for queuing the requests), however `.take` works way too slow compare to my benchmark of processing the load without using a queue.

Comment: When you don't use a queue, is that the only change or are you also changing things like how threads are used?

Comment: I needed two characteristics: remove head of the queue and block until an element is available ; can safely remove and add into the queue from multiple threads. I thought blockingqueue satisfies both of those requirements, but I would need to manually manage them if I were to use java.util.queue

Comment: Can you demonstrate a simple example where using a queue results in a delay even a fraction of what you are seeing because I can't so I don't know why you believe this is the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You state: "CPU usage is very very low - so the worker is not busy at all". You also say: "I have confirmed that blocking queue is not the thing causing the performance issue. Although I have not found the performance bottleneck in my application, but there has to be one somewhere."

If both of those statements are true, it might be that your worker thread spends a lot of time waiting on I/O. If so, there is a simple solution: run more than one worker thread!

Or it may be that there is some *other* concurrency bottleneck (not the work queue).

Why don't you do the following: make a little test program which pushes about 1,000 items on the work queue, and then starts running the same code which runs on the worker thread. When the queue is empty, it should exit. Profile that program. (Do you have a profiler set up on your dev machine? I like using JIP.)

Comment: Thank you very much. Later that day, I made some other benchmarks and profiled it using VisualVM, then confirmed that you are right - I did not realize that network connection is the bottleneck. I was benchmarking the server program from only one client connection, after I tried to benchmark it using 100 concurrent client connections, I got very satisfactory throughput. Lessons learned.

Comment: Glad this helped you... if network latency is the bottleneck, you should see *BIG* performance increases from running more worker threads! (BTW... a +1 would be appreciated.)

Answer (score 2):

The most likely explanation for what you are seeing is that the queue is empty causing `take()` to wait.  If the queue is not empty it can be very fast.

I assume in clojure the performance is similar to that in Java.

```
public static void main(String... args) throws InterruptedException {
    int runs = 20000;
    BlockingQueue<Integer> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer>(runs + 1);
    BlockingQueue<Integer> queue2 = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Integer>(runs + 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        testQueue(runs, queue);
        testTake(runs, queue);
        testQueue(runs, queue2);
        testTake(runs, queue2);
    }
}

private static void testQueue(int runs, BlockingQueue<Integer> queue) {
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    for (int i = 0; i < runs; i++)
        queue.offer(1);
    long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
    System.out.printf(queue.getClass().getSimpleName() + ": Average time to offer was %,d ns%n", time / runs);
}

private static void testTake(int runs, BlockingQueue<Integer> queue) throws InterruptedException {
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    for (int i = 0; i < runs; i++)
        queue.take();
    long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
    System.out.printf(queue.getClass().getSimpleName() + ": Average time to take was %,d ns%n", time / runs);
}
```

finally prints

```
ArrayBlockingQueue: Average time to offer was 34 ns
ArrayBlockingQueue: Average time to take was 39 ns
LinkedBlockingQueue: Average time to offer was 78 ns
LinkedBlockingQueue: Average time to take was 54 ns
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the code sample. In my scenario, I offer to the queue at a rate of approx. 2,000 elements / second, I observed that `.take` plus processing elements work at approx. 150 elements / second.

My benchmark shows that my app is capable of processing more than 8,000 elements / second. So I am still wondering whether it was `.take` that slows down my app, if so, why...

Comment: take will slow your application by about 100 nano-seconds.  However to make a program multi-thread you often have to make other changes like make data thread safe or shared between threads when previous it was not.  This can create more overhead than it is worth. The cause of your slow down is like to be in other changes you made. I would use a CPU profiler to identify the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the result is same with LinkedBlocingQueue and ArrayBlockingQueue? the efficiency of offering and taking element from the queue is different based on the difference of those 2 data structure.

Comment: Results are similar. `LinkedBlockingQueue.take` always works but extremely slow, `ArrayBlockingQueue.take` works faster than linked at the beginning, and completely stops working after few thousands of elements taken, and only works again after an extremely long delay (few minutes)

Comment: You can add some debug code to make sure the Queue is not empty when you call take(), because the program will be blocked if the queue is empty when call take().

Comment: Thank you. Yes I confirm that the queue had many thousands of elements available, but `.take` just takes way too long to return them.

Comment: Ok, then you can use some profiler tools to check which statement took the execution time in take() method. Java VisualVM is one option